# The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled

Tags: ffmpeg

My `ffmpeg` is showing this in the logs when I try to convert a video:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.flv output.mp4
...
[aac @ 0xf50860] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs
are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

Anyone help me solve this issue please?

Comment: I feel like that error message is just about as clear as it can get. It tells you what's wrong and how to fix it. I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: I think even if I fully agree to @Cairnarvon this *might* be useful to others googling for this problem.

Comment: The native FFmpeg AAC encoder is no longer marked as experimental, so recent `ffmpeg` builds no longer need `-strict -2` or `-strict experimental` to enable the encoder.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the advice in the error msg:

```
add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

therefore, just add the `-strict -2` command line option!

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247468/984586