# Avconv and "Unable to find a suitable output format" error

Tags: avconv, drawtext

Hi I want to add some text on a .mp4.

I'm trying this :

```
shell_exec("avconv -i input.mp4 drawtext=\"fontfile=OpenSans-Italic.ttf: text='Test Text'\" output.mp4").
```

But I get

> Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   'drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans-Italic.ttf: text='Test Text''
>   drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans-Italic.ttf: text='Test Text': Invalid
>   argument

Any idea of what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mistake with your argument `drawtext`. It is a filter but you need `-vf` before it so libav can understand what it is. Overall your command should be:

```
shell_exec("avconv -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"fontfile=OpenSans-Italic.ttf: text='Test Text'\" output.mp4")
```

This looks like php so I would also suggest you to check:

- Read/write permissions,
- Path of OpenSans-Italic.ttf file,
- Execution path vs file path
- Whether libav was compiled with `--enable-libfreetype` option (which is required for drawtext filter)

Source: https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#drawtext

Comment: Thank you it works but I think libav is not compiled with --enable-libfreetype because I got this error : "The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it."

Comment: I don't know your current error since my version works fine like that but here is another answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247468. Hope it helps!