# PHP/FFMPEG - why does my video conversion result in empty file?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video that lives on my server from a .webm to a .mp4.

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.webm output.mp4');
```

However, this results in an empty mp4 (0 bytes - or, sometimes, and very weirdly, 28 bytes.) The input file exists, and is 45MB.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/392680/291209) recommended explicitly copying the input codec, but same result.

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.webm -vcodec copy -acodec-copy output.mp4');
```

What am I doing wrong?

[ ===== EDIT  ===== ]

After trying a few more things, inspired by the comments, I'm still having no joy converting to MP4.

It seems I'm running FFMPEG v.2.8.15. This seems quite a lot lower than the current release of 4~, however I only installed this a week or so ago so I'm not sure why this is the case and I don't know how to update it (I'm on WHM Cpanel.)

Anyway, my problem is NOT to do with pathing, because the same command works fine if I change .mp4 to .webm - I get a successfully converted .webm file.

But when I run:

```
$foo = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.webm -vcodec copy -acodec copy output3.mp4 -report');
```

...I get [this FFMPEG log output](https://tuitionkit.com/ffmpeg-log.txt).

I've also tried:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i file.webm -r 24 KKK.mp4 -report');
```

...from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148739/1352288), and

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i file.webm -c:v copy III.mp4');

...from [this article](https://addpipe.com/blog/converting-webm-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg/).

Both result in the same problem, i.e. an 0-bytes .mp4 file.

Comment: You'll need to show the complete log from the `ffmpeg` command. Either will do.

Comment: what is the output when you run over terminal w/o shell_exec?

Comment: `-acodec -copy` not `-acodec-copy`. Better to make sure you also have an up to date ffmpeg and use the newer syntax: `-c:v copy` `-c:a copy`

Comment: Sorry, typo above: I'll try again: `-acodec copy` not `-acodec-copy`. Better to make sure you also have an up to date ffmpeg and use the newer syntax: `-c:v copy` `-c:a copy`

Comment: You probably need to specify the full paths to the files, and possibly the executable as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I'll have a look at what the log output is. @miken32 - I don't think so, because the same command is working fine if I convert to .webm rather than .mp4. And the file IS created, as I said - just with 0 bytes.

Comment: You can use the -report option of ffmpeg in order to get the log output (or capture stderr which is a bit harder to do ;-)), this should tell you whats the problem is

Comment: Hey guys - please see question edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

You're trying to mux VP9 video and Opus audio into the MP4 container. Currently, muxing Opus into the MP4 container is considered experimental and requires `-strict experimental` (or `-strict -2`), but your `ffmpeg` is too old to support that. [Download a new version](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

## Solutions

- Do not mux typical WebM formats (VP9 or VP8 + Opus or Vorbis) into MP4. You can re-encode it to H.264 (or H.265) with AAC audio if you want a more common set of formats for MP4:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
  ```
- Or upgrade your `ffmpeg` and add the `-strict experimental` (or `-strict -2`) output option to your command if you know you want VP9 + Opus in MP4:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input -c copy -strict experimental -movflags +faststart output.mp4
  ```
- Or don't re-mux into MP4 in the first place. HTML5 video supports VP9 + Opus in WebM so just use the original file if it is supported by your target browser(s).

Comment: Thanks for this. I would upgrade FFMPEG but I don't know how as I have very little server admin knowledge and I'm restricted to what I can do in WHM, running Centos 7 (I don't have access to the physical server). Secondly, I'm converting to MP4 because Safari on Mac (inc. iPhone) [doesn't support WEBM](https://www.webmproject.org/users/) so the idea was to convert to a second format that is supported.

Comment: Also the command you gave me under Solutions still resulted in a 0-bytes MP4 :-( The FFMPEG log says I need experimental for that; I turned it on, by appending -strict -2 to the command (I know you said my version was too old to use experimental, but I tried anyway) and I got the same result - 0 bytes and a complaint that I need to use experimental.

Comment: @Utkanos Using `-strict -2`/`-strict experimental` is not a generic catch-all: it is needed when you are attempting to use specific experimental features. You are encountering two different cases. The old FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`) used to be considered experimental, so that is why your old `ffmpeg` requires `-strict -2` to use that. Modern version do not require `-strict` for that encoder. Your old `ffmpeg` does not support Opus in MP4, but modern versions do, but they require `-strict` for this.

Comment: Thanks, @LordNeckbeard. Lastly, is it straightforward for a server noob, in my situation, to update my version of ffmpeg? I've looked at the download page you linked, and I have no idea which link I'm supposed to click for my server build (Centos 7) or what I do with it. I'm more than happy to go learn, I just need a kickstart to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Utkanos I'll provide that answer in your [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1372260/ffmpeg-why-do-i-end-up-with-old-version-after-installing) in a little while. This answer here will specifically address the Opus in MP4 issue.

Comment: Please see edit @LordNeckBeard - continued thanks for your help.

Comment: Turns out the `-strict` flag has to go in a certain place, which certainly isn't made clear in the FFMPEG logs. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247468/1352288) cleared that up. So now I'm all good - huge thanks for your help along the way.

Comment: @Utkanos Option order is important: `ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output` and you should avoid trailing options as they are often ignored (as you experienced).